# What is the difference between microtask and macrotask in javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I'd like to understand the definition of both and the difference and I attempt to find the difference and I didn't find anything

Comment: you can learn more about concepts like `Macrotask`, `Microtask` and `Event Loop` here: https://javascript.info/event-loop

Comment: Note that at least for HTML, there is no "macrotask", only tasks, microtasks being a special kind of tasks.